# Sahi OpenSource to store data from web application and to open office

Tags: openoffice-calc, sahi

I am new to automation. I am trying to fetch data from an application and store it in excel format. It can be done using Ms Excel but can the same be done by using Open Office?
I am using Sahi OpenSource

Comment: Says here (http://sahi.co.in/sahi-open-source/) Sahi can "connect" to Excel and CSV. Both formats can be opened and saved in OpenOffice. As there is no way to "connect" to a comma seperated values text file, this probably means it can write one that you can load in OpenOffice later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are storing a data in some excel file, it doesn't matters whether you store it from Ms Excel or open office. You have the excel or csv file to which Sahi will write directly. You can write to excel files or csv files or text file even from Sahi. I would encourage you to look at sahi documentation regarding writing to files.